# Events cleanup in c#

Tags: c#, events

Let's say I have two objects A and B. A publish an event, and B is subscribed to this event. I know B can unsubscribe using the -= sintaxis, but is there any way to B to unlink from all events without going one by one?

I know A can iterate throught all clients using the GetInvocationList method, but I'm asking for B. I'm thinking in something like that as a way to ensure B code is not executed anymore due to an event and that I'm not forgiven any event.

thanks

Comment: why dont you change Code for B .. use return

Comment: There is no inbuilt Methods for getting all Events , that a Method has been registered for

Comment: No. When B subscribes to an event of A, B has no "knowledge" of A.

Comment: Unlike everybody, I would say that would be possible. It is not supported natively, though. You must implement it (using GetInvocationList and a bit of reflection).
But in this case, B must keep a reference of A, and since A has a reference on B through the event, this might cause a memory leak if not used properly.

Comment: That said, this is not a clean pattern :)

Comment: So I suppose the unique solution is to be very carefully and ensure you unsubscribe under all situations given that there is no way to get rid of all the events in a simple way. It's a pitty because if you forget one event...

Comment: You could use weak events. It's quite a lot more work, but it will solve your problem if you want to avoid memory leaks. (e.g. see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: weak events sounds interesting if you have access to the publisher code (and I have) although I will need to do lots of changes

Comment: You could customize the `add` parts of your events of A to call a function in B which passes a delegate to unsubscribe this event. It's actually quite simple, but a bit hackish. I'll give you an example if you want....

Comment: I do not fully understand the underlying problem. Do you want B to stay alive but simply non-reactive to events? Or do you fear that a method of B is called after B was disposed?

Comment: @BernhardHiller, the second. In other scenarios maybe the first too (but I reckon I wouldn't like this approach)

Answer (score 1):

Although this is only a problem when B outlives A, it can happen.

The only way to do that is to keep track of all event subscriptions.

For the event provider, there's a class that easily manages subscribers: [EventHandlerList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList.aspx). You would have to create your own for manage subscribed events.

Or you clould use the [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609) to manage the event subscriptions.

Comment: I think it's a problem when A outlives B, isn't it? If B is dumped, A should lose the reference to B so B isn't kept in memory for still being referenced.

Comment: If you use something like the `EventHandlerList` on A, there's not a problem. And the only problem would be a resource leak. Regarding B the problem is that it keeps receiving events.